# What is no matching function call error in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I created a class, whose base class was `QObject`, Now if I try to add a `QTextBrowser` in my code, I get the error as no matching function for call to `QTextBrowser`. I tried to compile the code by adding `QWidget` class but still I am unable to resolve the error. How can I resolve this.

[image: Here is the screenshot]

MainWindow code

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "window.h"
#include "bbbserver.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 QApplication app (argc, argv);

 bbbServer server;
 Window window;

 window.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);");
 window.showFullScreen();

 return app.exec();
}
```

Here is the code for window.h

```
#ifndef WINDOW_H
#define WINDOW_H

#include <QWidget>

class QPushButton;
class QTextBrowser;
class QProcess;
class QFile;

class Window : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    explicit Window(QWidget *parent = 0);
    QTextBrowser *statusWindow;


private slots:

};


#endif // WINDOW_H
```

Here is the code for window.cpp

```
#include "window.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QTextBrowser>
#include <QDebug>

Window::Window(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    // Create and position the buttons on the main window


  /*************** text browser *********************/
     statusWindow = new QTextBrowser(this);
     statusWindow->setMinimumSize(QSize(0,0));
     statusWindow->setMaximumSize(QSize(10000,10000));
     statusWindow->setGeometry(175, 50, 440, 420);
     statusWindow->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);");
```

`}`
Here is the code for bbbserver.h file

```
#ifndef BBBSERVER_H
#define BBBSERVER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>

class bbbServer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit bbbServer(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:
    void newConnection();

private:
        QTcpServer *server;
};

#endif // BBBSERVER_H
```

this is bbbserver.cpp file

```
#include "bbbserver.h"

bbbServer::bbbServer(QObject *parent):
    QObject(parent)
{


    /*************************** SERVER *********************************/
    server = new QTcpServer(this);
    connect(server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(newConnection()));

    if(!server->listen(QHostAddress::QHostAddress("192.168.0.1"), 5000))
    {
        qDebug() << "SERVER NOT STARTED";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "SERVER STARTED";
    }
}

void bbbServer::newConnection()
{
    QTcpSocket *socket= server->nextPendingConnection();
    socket->write("Connection from 192.168.0.1 BBB\n");
    socket->flush();
    socket->waitForBytesWritten(30000);

    socket->waitForReadyRead(30000);
    qDebug() << socket->readAll();
`HERE I WANT TO ACCESS THE STATUS WINDOW(textbrowser statusWindow)`
}
```

And this is the full error, which is same as in screenshot.

> bbbserver.cpp:8: error: no matching function for call to 'QTextBrowser::QTextBrowser(bbbServer* const)'

Comment: Please edit your question to include both the code and the full error message instead of posting screen shots.

Comment: @G.M. can you check it again

Comment: Isn't `this`the wrong type ?

Answer (score 0):

The `parent` parameter passed to the [`QTextBrowser` constructor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextbrowser.html#QTextBrowser) needs to be of type `QWidget *` whereas you're passing a `QObject *`.  If you really need the `bbbServer` to be the parent object of the `QTextBrowser` then simply do...

```
infoSpace = new QTextBrowser;
infoSpace->QObject::setParent(this);
```

**Note:** The `QObject::` qualifier is required because `QWidget::setParent(QWidget *)` effectively hides its base's `QObject::setParent(QObject *)` member meaning the latter won't take part in the normal lookup process.

Comment: Edited the answer.  Not quite sure why the `QObject::` qualifier is required in this case though.  I'll check the docs.

Comment: It got compiled this time, but how can I display it as widget. See I have A.h whose base class is QWidget and B.h whose base class is QObject. I want to have a widget which will be displayed on mainwindow and I can access it from the B.cpp . If I add textbrowser in A.cpp I can't access it from B.cpp

Comment: @user7345878 you obviously can't display a `QObject`, in your case I'd simply not add a `QTextBrowser` to your server (!) class at all. A better solution would be to create a signal that emits the "info text" or whatever you want to display in that text browser and then connect that signal to your main window (from your main window or whereever you create the `bbbServer` object). I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @xander I got what you are trying to say, but my problem how can access that textbrowser which is in another .h/.cpp file from this .cpp file The main issue is to access the variable of another class from a different class file.

Comment: @user7345878 yeah it seems like many developers here have that problem every day, to me it's basic C++/OOP, you just define a get method for that member field and access it, you need an object of your class for that of course. :) something like this in your public declarations (e.g. below your constructor): `QTextBrowser* infoSpaceBrowser() const { return infoSpace; }` then you can access it wherever you have an `bbbServer` object `bbbServer server; server.infoSpaceBrowser();`

Comment: @xander sorry i didn't understood. I have edited the question, added full code. Can you have a look now ?

Comment: @user7345878 ok if you really want to use it like that, you have to get a pointer to your `Window` or the `QTextBrowser` from your `bbbServer::newConnection()` method. Since the code doesn't show how you create your `Window` or anything I can only guess. But in this case it would be easiest to set that pointer from your `MainWindow` or where you have access to your `Window` and your `bbbServer` and then do something like this: `server.setWindow(window)` (assuming server is object of your bbbServer and window your Window. then use `window->textBrowser()` in your method.You need some set/getter.

Comment: @xander, if I create a pointer to Window in MainWindow. The GUI get terminated by a signal. Here is the MainWindow Code.

Comment: @user7345878 what do you mean gets terminated? You should use something like `server.setWindow(&window);` or if you just want a pointer to your `QTextBrower` use `server.setTextBrowser(window.textBrowser());` with the appropiate setters and getters. WIth a signal in your server it would be easier and better maintainable, just saying :)